# POSTGRES ERROR: INTO used with a command that cannot return data

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-migration

Am trying to execute the variable t_ord which has statement "REVOKE role_test FROM test" . My requirement is to execute the variable t_ord and store the result msg successfull or fail in the variable ret . But am getting the below error ,

ERROR:  INTO used with a command that cannot return data
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 9 at EXECUTE

```
    DO $$
 declare
  t_ord varchar(500):= NULL;
  cursor_name numeric;
  ret varchar(500):= NULL;
 begin
SELECT 'REVOKE '||'role_test'||' FROM '||'test' INTO STRICT t_ord ;
raise notice 't_ord %',t_ord;
/*
 cursor_name := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
      DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cursor_name, t_ord, DBMS_SQL.V7);
      ret      := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cursor_name);
      DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_name);
*/
EXECUTE t_ord ; -- > not getting desired results as commented code above , cursor_name should be used which is required later in exception block

EXCEPTION
/*   WHEN err THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION '%', t_msg;
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
         IF DBMS_SQL.IS_OPEN(cursor_name) THEN
            DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_name);
         END IF;
    RAISE;
*/
  WHEN SQLSTATE '50001' THEN
      RAISE NOTICE '%', t_msg;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM pg_cursors WHERE name = 'cursor_name') THEN
        CLOSE cursor_name;
     END IF;
END;

 end $$;
```

And , How can i implement cursor_name the same way in oracle so that it can be used in exception block ..

Comment: You don't need a cursor to run dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

The declaration `cursor_name numeric;` does not make any sense to me. If you want a cursor (which does not seem to be needed here to begin with) you need to declare it as `cursor`, not `numeric` You also never open a cursor to begin with. And `DBMS_SQL.PARSE` is not a standard Postgres function looks like you are trying to migrate some Oracle code.

You are also referencing a variable `t_msg` that you did not declare. But the error message of the current error is automatically available in the variable `SQLERRM`

There is also no ([documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html)) SQLSTATE 50001 in Postgres, so I am unsure which error you want to trap there.

As far as I can tell, your code can be simplified to:

```
DO $$
declare
  t_ord text;
begin
   -- no need for a SELECT to assign a variable
   t_ord := 'REVOKE role_test FROM test';

   raise notice 't_ord %', t_ord;

   EXECUTE t_ord;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE NOTICE '%', SQLERRM;
END;
$$;
```

You don't really need dynamic SQL to begin with, but I assume to simplified your example. To generate the correct REVOKE statement within a PL/pgSQL block, you should be using `format` to properly handle identifiers in a SQL statements, e.g. assuming you have a variable named, `t_role_name` and `t_user_name` you should use something like:

```
t_ord := format('REVOKE %I FROM %I', t_role_name, t_user_name);
```

Comment: Thank you , i implemented it the same way and it works fine as expected result :)